# Subgroups and an union of orbits

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

I have to prove or disprove the following statement:

> If a group $G$ acts on a set $X$, then every subgroup $H$ of $G$ acts on the set $X$ as well, and every orbit of the action $G$ on $X$ is an union of orbits of the action $H$ on $X$.'

But I have absolutely no clue what they mean with this question. The question is translated from Dutch, so I hope that I didn't make mistakes while translating it. What I don't understand is what the action $G$ on $X$ means and what a union of orbits should be.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of replacing "works" with the standard term "acts", but please revert any changes that don't preserve your intended meaning.

Comment: Here is the Wikipedia article on group actions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action Is there some aspect in particular you have questions about?

Comment: The Wikipedia is rather clear, thank you for sending it! Well I understand group actions in terms of the dihedral group acting on a structure. But I can't make this abstract terminology into something clear...

Comment: You're welcome. It may be helpful to think of a group action as encoding (at least part of) the symmetry of an object. Like you say, the dihedral groups are natural examples, because they act on regular polygons (which in turn have dihedral symmetry), simply by reflects and rotations.

Comment: One can also think of actions algebraically, namely, as maps $G \times X \to X$ that obey certain relations that encode exactly the conditions that they *do* act by symmetries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, an action of a group $G$ on a set $X$ is a group homomorphism from $G$ to the group $S_X$ of permutations of the set $X$. This means that we send each group element $g \in G$ to some permutation of the elements in $X$, so each group element "acts" on $X$ by permuting its elements in some way. Usually, we write $g \cdot x$ to denote the element of $X$ that $x$ is sent to by the permutation in $S_X$ that corresponds to $g \in G$.

Then the *orbit* of a point $x \in X$ is the set of all points of $X$ that we can reach by applying elements of $g$ to $x$. In formula: $\text{Orb}(x) = G(x) = \{g \cdot x: g \in G\}$. This is a subset of $X$.

You are given a group $G$ with a subgroup $H$ and some action $G \to S_X$. Does this also give an action of $H$ on $X$? Yes, it does, because the composition of the homomorphisms $H \to G$ (inclusion) and $G \to S_X$ gives a homomorphism $H \to S_X$. Loosely speaking, since we can apply elements of $G$ to elements of $X$ we can do the same with elements of $H \subset G$. Since $H$ is a group under the group operation of $G$, this gives a well defined action of a group on a set.

Now we have two actions on $X$: one from $G$ and one from $H$. We also have orbits from both actions, partitioning $X$. (So we have two partitions of $X$: one into the orbits of the action of $G$, and one into the orbits of the action of $H$.) The question asks whether it is true that any orbit of $G$ (as a subset of $X$) is a union of orbits of $H$ (which are subsets of $X$ as well).

For instance, the dihedral group $D_4$ acts naturally on the vertices of a square (a set $X$ with $4$ points). $D_4$ has a cyclic subgroup $H$ with two elements, corresponding with reflecting in a (let's say horizontal) side of the square. The action of $D_4$ is transitive, so there is one orbit: $X$ itself. The action of $H$ has two orbits, one consisting of the upper two vertices and one consisting of the lower two vertices of the square. So, in this case, any $G$-orbit is a union of $H$-orbits: the only $G$-orbit $X$ is the union of the two $H$-orbits. The question is whether this holds for all group actions.

I hope this makes the question clear to you!

And to give you a hint to solve it: because $X$ is partitioned both by the $H$- and the $G$-orbits, it suffices to prove that any $H$-orbit is contained in only one $G$-orbit.

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive explanation! I understand most of what you're saying, but I don't understand the notation $S_X$. What does this mean when you are talking about $D_4$? But apart from this I think I understand the question right now.

Comment: $S_X$ depends only on the set $X$, not on the group $G$. It is the group consisting of all permutations of the set $X$, with composition as group operation. If $X$ has $n$ elements this group is isomorphic to $S_n$, the symmetric group on $n$ elements. For instance when $X = \{A, B, C\}$ then $S_X$ has $6$ elements: the identity, the permutation that swaps $A$ and $B$, the permutation that swaps $B$ and $C$, the permutation that swaps $C$ and $A$ and two cyclic permutations.

Answer (score 0):

It is a two step proof:

1. Show that an element belonging to a certain orbit is an equivalence relation. [Refer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2430073/prove-that-is-in-the-same-g-orbit-as-is-an-equivalence-relation)
2. Show that equivalence relation partitions set into disjoint smaller sets whose total union unions give back original set. [Refer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2451056/prove-that-equivalence-relation-on-a-set-is-analogous-to-a-partition-of-a-set)

Answer (score 0):

As for the second part, recall that every $g\in G$ lays in some right coset of $H$ in $G$. So, denoted with $R\subseteq G$ a complete set of coset representatives, for $x\in X$ we get:
\begin{alignat}{1}
\operatorname{Orb}_G(x) &= \{g\cdot x, g\in G\} \\
&= \{(hg_i)\cdot x, g_i\in R \text{ and } h\in H\} \\
&= \{h\cdot(g_i\cdot x), g_i\in R \text{ and } h\in H\} \\
&= \{h\cdot y_i, y_i\in Y(x)\subseteq \operatorname{Orb}_G(x) \text{ and } h\in H\} \\
&= \bigcup_{y_i\in Y(x)}\{h\cdot y_i, h\in H\} \\
&= \bigcup_{y_i\in Y(x)}\operatorname{Orb}_H(y_i) \\
\end{alignat}
where $Y(x):=\{g_i\cdot x, g_i\in R\}$.  So, the claim is true.